# Higher order component to overwrite function parameter

Tags: typescript

I sometimes find myself wanting to write a HOC that takes a function, fixes one of its parameters with a specific value and returns a function that takes all of the original functions parameters except those that were fixed. I cannot find a way to do this with proper TypeScript support.

I have tried numerous things along these lines:

```
function overideFunctionParams< OverrideProps, ReturnType, FuncProps>(
    func: (props: FuncProps & OverrideProps) => ReturnType,
    override: OverrideProps
): (props: FuncProps) => ReturnType {
    return (props: FuncProps) => func({ ...props, ...override });
}

const iTakeAB = (props: {a: string, b: string}) => console.log(props)

const newFunc = overideFunctionParams(iTakeAB, {a: "hello"})
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WoMPLN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found an answer I am somewhat happy with.

```
function InjectOverwriteParameters<
FuncProps,
OverrideType extends Partial<FuncProps>,
ReturnType
>(func: (props: FuncProps) => ReturnType, override: OverrideType) 
{
  return (props: Omit<FuncProps, keyof OverrideType>) =>
    func({ ...override, ...props } as FuncProps);
}

const iTakeAB = (props: { a: string; b: string }) => 


const newFunc = InjectOverwriteParameters(iTakeAB, { b: "asdf" 
});
```

This behaves as desired, newFunc({a: "somestring", "b: "someother string"}) complains about the property b not being part of the desired input while accepting {a: "somestring}.

Comment: Is there a reason you have that fourth type parameter? That is: why not just do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/mb3YdW) without it?

Comment: Nope! This is a straight up improvement, thanks, I'll modify the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**